# How to reinstall/restore fonts on ubuntu 14.04? Install completely unusable

Tags: 14.04, fonts

I tried to install some fonts on Ubuntu and instead messed up rendering fonts on ubuntu altogether.

Currently, all fonts in all apps (except for Chrome which I'm typing in now) render characters as 'empty squares', including the system itself such as terminal, etc.

Of course this is completely unusable. 
Last thing I remembered trying was something like (to get newly installed fonts to work (from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1976037)

`sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/*`

Could this have caused the issue? 
Anyone got any clue what to try to get Ubuntu running normal again?